# variable problems, a = b is messing up value of b if i update a; javaScript

Tags: javascript

if i set variable A equal to variable B then sometimes when i update value of a then b is also updated.

```
var b = 0;
var a = b;
b++;
```

now both `a` and `b` returns `1`; why?

I know what you all mean, even the part about the objects, i use firefox to run my code on codepen. Usually the code runs fine but every once in a while this sort of problem comes up.

I found a solution:-
when the happens it must be happening because some how the compiler is reading the variables as objects.
so ii tried the following solution and it worked.

```
var b = 0;
var a = JSON.stringify(b);
a = JSON.parse(a);
a++;
// now a returns 1 and b returns 0 thanks for helping
```

Comment: sure about that? `a==0` is true in the console after running above...

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I just tried this out in the console of chrome. The result is: a = 0, b = 1 (which is expected). Could you post your whole code? Maybe there is a bug in it...

Comment: There's no way your original code could be doing what you say. It's just not the way Javascript works.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/j7vvuu7j/

Comment: The question is not "my code can't do this" the question is "my code is doing this". I don't know why but JS is considering b as an object. I was hoping someone with with more experience can point out a reason but how can I forget that the net if full of trolls.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive values are passed by value but objects are always passed by reference.. this can only happen when you're talking about objects.

```js
var a = 0,
    b = a;

a = 3;
console.log(a, b); // will be different

a = {a: 0};
b = a;

a.a = 3;
console.log(a, b); // will be the same
```